# Bogus escape error when running regex

Tags: python, regex

Yesterday, I got help with the regex matching which worked well as a standalone. But when put into this code, I am getting the "bogus escape error". The code and traceback are below. Could you please point me to what I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

sf = open("a.txt","r")
out = open("b.txt","w")
regex = re.compile(r'Merging\s+\d+[^=]*=\s*\'\w+@\w+\x\w+\'\\"')


for line in sf:
    m = regex.findall(line)
    for i in m:
       print >> out,line,
```

The traceback is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     `File "match.py", line 6, in <module>
>       regex = re.compile(r'Merging\s+\d+[^=]*=\s*\'\w+@\w+\x\w+\'\\"')
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
>       return _compile(pattern, flags)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
>       raise error, v # invalid expression
>   sre_constants.error: bogus escape: '\\x'`

Comment: To match a literal `r'\x'`, you need another forward slash before the `'x'`, see http://regex101.com/r/oE5pS2/1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\x` is not a valid special sequence. If you want to match a literal `\x`, you need to escape the backslash using `\\x` or if you need something else, use a [valid one](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), such as you did with `\w`.

This will compile:

```
re.compile(r'Merging\s+\d+[^=]*=\s*\'\w+@\w+\\x\w+\'\\"')
```

Answer (score 2):

`\x` must be followed by a hex value (i.e. exactly two hex digits):

```
>>> '\x61'
'a'
>>> '\x'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape
```

If you want to match a *literal* `\x` then you can escape the backslash so that the `x` is not being escaped: `\\x`.